# Arduino: Why doesn't my stepper move in reverse direction?

Tags: arduino

I have verified that its not a wiring problem by using some non library example code, so it seems the problem is not with the circuit.

I'm expecting the following code to run the motor in one direction 200 steps then run 200 steps in the opposite direction.  It seems to run the initial 200 steps but then stops, why?

In the `setup` function:

```
stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
// Set the maximum speed in steps per second:
stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
```

In the `loop` function:

```
 while(stepper.currentPosition() < 300){
   stepper.moveTo(200);
   stepper.setSpeed(200);
   stepper.run();
   
  if (stepper.distanceToGo() == 0) {
      stepper.moveTo(-stepper.currentPosition());
      stepper.setSpeed(200);
      stepper.run();
  }

 }
```

Here's my entire code.  The `if/else` at the bottom is where I want to run the motor.  I've put in some non working example code in this block as an example:

```
#include <deprecated.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <MFRC522Extended.h>
#include <require_cpp11.h>
// Include the AccelStepper library:
#include <AccelStepper.h>


// constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int BUTTON_PIN = 2; // the number of the pushbutton pin
#define BLUE 7
#define GREEN 6
#define RED 3
#define RST_PIN 9     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN  53   // Configurable, see typical pin layout above


#define dirPin 10
#define stepPin 11
#define motorInterfaceType 1


// Variables will change:
String authKeyFob = "123456789";
String card_ID="";
int ledState         = 0;     // remember current led state
int buttonState      = 0;  
int oldButtonState = 0;
bool toggle = false;

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance
AccelStepper stepper = AccelStepper(motorInterfaceType, stepPin, dirPin);

void setup() {

  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
 
  while (!Serial);     // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
  SPI.begin();         // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();  // Init MFRC522 card


  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an pull-up input
  // the pull-up input pin will be HIGH when the switch is open and LOW when the switch is closed.
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);

  stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
  stepper.setAcceleration(50);
 // stepper.setSpeed(200);
 // stepper.moveTo(200);
  
}

void loop() {
 
/*
  // Change direction once the motor reaches target position
  if (stepper.distanceToGo() == 0) {
    stepper.moveTo(-stepper.currentPosition());
  }
  // Move the motor one step
  stepper.run();
*/
  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);


  // read the state of the switch/button:
  oldButtonState = LOW;    //  NEED TO ADD A DECLARATION FOR THIS BEFORE SETUP
  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

  // Look for new cards, and select one if present
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() ) {

  }
 

  if(mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ){
      card_ID="";
      for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
         card_ID += mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
      }

      if(card_ID == authKeyFob){
        toggle = !toggle;
        delay(200);
      }
  }

  //  if the button just became pressed...
  if(buttonState == HIGH && oldButtonState==LOW){
    toggle = !toggle;  // same thing, toggle our variable. 
    delay(200);
  }
  

  if (toggle) {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
    stepper.moveTo(200);
    stepper.setSpeed(200);
    stepper.run();
       
  } else {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
    stepper.moveTo(200);
    stepper.setSpeed(200);
    stepper.run();

  }
  oldButtonState = buttonState;  // save the button state for next time

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code moves the stepper in each direction.

```
  if (toggle) {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RED, LOW);
    while(stepper.currentPosition() <= 200){
      stepper.moveTo(200);
      stepper.setSpeed(200);
      stepper.runSpeedToPosition();
      if(stepper.currentPosition()==200){
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
    while(stepper.currentPosition() >= -200){
      stepper.moveTo(-200);
      stepper.setSpeed(200);
      stepper.runSpeedToPosition();
      if(stepper.currentPosition()==-200){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The run method doesn't block.  It just takes one step if it is time.  So let's step through your code.  First we enter the while loop and tell it to step to 200 and set the speed and call run.  We keep repeating that over and over.  If we get to a point where we have 0 to go then you say moveTo the negative position, set the speed, call run once and then the while loop exits and repeats.  On that repeat we say move to 200 and start calling run on that.  So you're only calling run once with the moveTo set to the negative number.

You need to rethink the logic on this.  I don't know what else is in your loop, so it's hard to say what exactly you want.  If you really insist on it being blocking in the while loop then:

```
stepper.moveTo(200);
stepper.setSpeed(200);
while(stepper.distanceToGo() != 0){
   stepper.run();
}
stepper.moveTo(-200);
while(stepper.distanceToGo != 0){
   stepper.run();
}
```

Comment: I might need to rethink this.  I basically have a toggle setup with LEDs and I want the motor to run one way when red, the other when green at the speed set of 200.

Comment: OK, add code to what I just posted that sets the leds how you want.  It's just a couple of digitalWrite statements.  Right there where you set the moveTo value.

Comment: Yeah, that was already working, I was then adding the motor.  Its still not quite right though.  I'll spend a bit more time on it thought.

Comment: I can’t help you with code I can’t see.  When you want help add the rest of the code and talk about what you want it to do.

Comment: I've added my entire code.  Your code works within the loop function, I can't get it to work with the LEDs at the correct speed.  Runs slow within the loop function (no while loop).

Comment: Did you mean to tell the stepper to move the same direction in both cases?

Comment: You copied this code from me, why did you do this:  oldButtonState = LOW;.  Shouldn't oldButtonState be whatever the buttonState was on the last loop?  It shouldn't always be low.  If the old state was HIGH then you don't want to toggle your toggle variable again.  You want to wait until it gets released and pressed again right?

Comment: My bad, stepper should be moving in a different direction in both cases.  The button state is functioning as expected.  I've actually made some progress by using `runToNewPosition()`

Comment: runToNewPosition is blocking isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I think it did.. I'm using runSpeedToPosition now, seems to work.  Not exactly sure about blocking and the problem with it though.

Comment: Blocking:  Imagine that I told you you have a job to do today at noon and at 6pm.  Imagine that I told you the only thing you were allowed to do between those times was to look at the clock and count the seconds.  That's blocking.  You can't eat.  You can't use the bathroom.  You can't do anything but one thing at a time.  Now imagine I told you just to check the clock every few seconds to see if it is time for your job but in the mean time you can do whatever you want.  That is non blocking.

Comment: To put in programming terms, imagine you call runToPosition and then you want to be able to press a button to abort that.  Since runToPosition is blocking, only that one command is running until you get to your position.  It's not going to check the button.  Now imagine the loop function is checking the button and calling run and repeating instead.  Every few microseconds it checks the button and calls run().  Only occasionally does run() do anything, but now you are also constantly checking your button and can abort if you want.  Google the terms.  They're not hard to understand.

Comment: Newbies tend to write a program like a linear story, first this happens then wait so long then this happens and then the next thing, all in a nice list of things that have to happen.   Instead the loop function should work like a huge checklist.  It should repeat thousands of times per second and only when it comes up that something needs to be done take that one tiny step and move on and keep checking the checklist.  This allows you to be able to do more than one thing at a time.   To see this in action, change your program now so that the LED blinks instead of on constant.  You can't.

Comment: That really helps understanding blocking, thank you very much.  Thank for all your help too, sincerely appreciated.